# Using threads with repaint() in the JApplet class causes it to "paint" over the paint

Tags: java, multithreading, repaint, japplet

I'm trying to understand this tutorial I've looked up for working with Applets with Java (http://www.javakode.com/applets/06-threads/), but I'm having a problem.

Whenever I'm using threads to `repaint()`, the previous generated imagery doesn't disappears.  It stays on the screen and draws a new image.  But this only happens when I'm using the `JApplet` class, but when I use the `Applet` class it works just fine.

What could be going wrong? Is it something on my end?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, the example doesn't honor the paint chain.  Paint delegates it's operations to a number of sub methods, one of which actually clears the `Graphics` context, ready for painting...

The mechanism for painting an AWT component is different then painting a Swing component

I would suggest...

1. Move you custom painting to separate component, something like `JPanel`.  It is double buffered and will prevent flickering when the component is repainted.
2. Have a read through [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)
3. Have a read through [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)
4. Use a `JFrame` instead, it's simpler...

Comment: If he is writing an Applet telling him to use a JFrame is non-sensical. JApplet is the correct top-level container to use for an swing application that runs in the browser.

Comment: A lot of pele start writing applets because that's the tutorials they fine on the net. It's easier to learn to start from JFrame and learn the basics without all the hassles that an applet brings, besides, with Java Web Start, we no longer need to be restricted to applets only. Besides, you really want to do browser based Java development, use JavaFX

Comment: I see, you were saying to start learning on the desktop with a JFrame rather than start out by dealing with the quirks of a JApplet. Makes sense.